# Prevent Magento from caching query strings, such as limit param

Tags: magento, query-string

#### The behavior

I what to display only 3 products per page. So in my catalog.xml I have

```
<action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>3</limit></action>
<action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>3</limit></action>
```

If I go to /category.html I will see only 3 products. It works, great!

But also I want to be able to show all products at once, so I add to the catalog.xml the following:

```
<action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>999</limit></action>
```

Now, if I navigate to /category.html?limit=999 I can see all the categories products, as expected.

#### The problem:

When I come back to /category.html, with no limit params, it displays all the products instead of the 3 I wish it did. It happends because Magento caches the limit preference.

#### The question:

Is there a configuration that prevents magento from caching listing options?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the toolbar block there is a method called `disableParamsMemorizing`. This should disable the storing of parameters in session.
Try to add this in the toolbar block.

```
<action method="disableParamsMemorizing" />
```

or you can override the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` class and make the `getToolbarBlock` method look like this:

```
public function getToolbarBlock()
{
    if ($blockName = $this->getToolbarBlockName()) {
        if ($block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock($blockName)) {
            $block->disableParamsMemorizing();
            return $block;
        }
    }
    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->_defaultToolbarBlock, microtime());
    $block->disableParamsMemorizing();
    return $block;
}
```

Comment: The first tip did it!. Thank you very much. I had the workaround `if(!isset($_GET['limit'])) { $_GET['limit'] = 3; }` in my index.php

Comment: where to add <action method="disableParamsMemorizing" />(in which file)

Comment: I hope I remember this right (6.5 years have passed). in `catalog.xml` inside (child tag) the declaration of the toolbar block.